# How to make another activity implement listener

Tags: android

I simplified my code for you to get better understanding it. 
I have `MyAdapter` and `MyActivity` working both perfectly.

```java
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView... {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...

    holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((Listener) context).onSelected(object);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}

class MyActivity implements MyAdapter.Listener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onSelected(Object object) {
        // do things with object here
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to make my another activity `MyAnotherActivity` implement `MyAdapter.Listener`. 
When I run my app, and click on my object, an overriden `onSelected()` just ignored.

```java
public class MyAnotherActivity implements MyAdapter.Listener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onSelected(Object object) {
        Log.e("MyAnotherActivity", "This text doesn't shows");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does `MyAnotherActivity` use an instance of `MyAdapter`? Are you sure that's set up properly, similar to `MyActivity`?

Comment: `MyAnotherActivity` is entirely separate from `MyActivity`. I think you simplified the code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The used `Listener` implementation depends on the `context` parameter passed to `MyAdapter` constructor. Because on this line `((Listener) context).onSelected(object);` you are casting the `context` field of the MyAdapter class to `Listener` implementation.

So when you are calling the constructor of the `MyAdapter`, you need to pass the context of `MyAnotherActivity`.

```
public class MyAnotherActivity implements MyAdapter.Listener {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
         MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this /*Context of MyAnotherActivity*/, ...);
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement any methods inside of any class (not just activity) , you can use EventBus, a lightweight library for passing messages and events around.

It's very easy to implement and the code samples  will help you out along the way
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/